# Queries being run twice on sql.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sql.js

I'm using SQLite with sql.js on my project and I have been having some trouble with my implementation. Seems like the queries are being run on the database twice because for the for the INSERT statements I get 2 records in the DB.

The way I do it, I create the SQL and then pass it on to this method (the opts variable contains all of the data being put into the database):

```
prepareStatementAndCompileResults(db, sql, opts){
   const stmt = db.prepare(sql); 
   const result = stmt.getAsObject(opts);
   var rows = [];
   if(!this.isEmpty(result)){ // isEmpty is a simple method that checks for empty objects
      rows.push(result);
   } 
   while(stmt.step()) {
      var row = stmt.getAsObject();
      rows.push(row); 
   }
   this.saveToFile(db);
   stmt.free();
   return rows; 
},
```

Here is a sample SQL INSERT that is being run twice

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tag_event (tag_id, event_id, unique_string) 
  VALUES (:tag_id,:event_id, :unique);
```

Here is what the opts variable would look like for this query:

```
var opts = {
   [':tag_id']: 1,
   [':event_id']:1, 
   [':unique']: '1-1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're pushing it into row 2 time.

```
// if not empty will add to row
if(!this.isEmpty(result)){ // isEmpty is a simple method that checks for empty objects
    rows.push(result);
} 


// not sure what step() does but I'm assuming this will also run
while(stmt.step()) {
      var row = stmt.getAsObject();
      rows.push(row); 
}
```

Verify by using a debugger or just `console.log(rows)` after the while loop before the save

Answer (score 0):

So, what it turns out I needed to do was bind the variables to the prepared statement before getting the rather than binding them through `getAsObject`. This is much more efficient. My API response time on a local test went from 785ms to 14.5ms

```
prepareStatementAndCompileResults(db, sql, opts){
    const rows = [];
    const stmt = db.prepare(sql); 
    stmt.bind(opts);

    while(stmt.step()) {
       var row = stmt.getAsObject();
       rows.push(row); 
    }
    this.saveToFile(db);
    stmt.free();
    return rows; 
},
```